# What is the German government's rationale for not allowing Leopard 2 tanks to be given to Ukraine?

Tags: ukraine, military, germany

There are many news articles today about how the German government is reluctant to allow Leopard 2 tanks to be given to Ukraine. For example, the BBC [reports](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-64341337):

> Under German law, the government in Berlin would have to give its permission before countries such as Poland or Finland could commit to re-exporting them. [...]
> Berlin was reported this week to have made a decision on the Leopard conditional on the US agreeing to send Abrams tanks, which it is not intending to do. [...] There are fears of escalation in Berlin and of going it alone.

I've skimmed about a dozen popular news articles now but am still none the wiser as to what the German government thinks would be bad about providing / allowing other countries to provide tanks specifically, or providing tanks despite the US not doing so.

### What I've found so far

Some of the attempts at explanation I've found in popular news media so far and why they are unsatisfactory:

#### Depletion of Germany's own arsenal

This is claimed to be one explanation offered by the German government in [a Deutsche Welle article](https://www.dw.com/en/why-isnt-germany-supplying-ukraine-with-heavy-weapons/a-61553273). The article quotes a defense expert who says this is nonsense, but even if it wasn't, it wouldn't explain why Germany is also blocking other NATO countries like Poland from sending its Leopard 2 tanks to Ukraine.

#### Not wanting to anger Russia

An article in [The Hill](https://thehill.com/policy/defense/3820367-how-us-german-bickering-is-blocking-ukraines-push-for-tanks/) claims one motivation behind the US and Germany deadlocking each other on the tank issue is that

> [...] then both countries get to avoid sending something they consider provocative to the Kremlin,”

But why would tanks be more provocative than all the other weapon systems sent so far?

#### Dependence on Russian energy

This is a variant of the point above in that it relies on the idea that tanks would be considered especially provocative by Russia, but it's only implied in one half-sentence of [a Reuters article](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/why-is-germany-not-sending-ukraine-heavy-weapons-2022-04-21/):

> Members of the SPD have defended Scholz and warned of being drawn into what could be considered a direct confrontation with Russia. Germany is also heavily dependent on Russian energy.

So the idea is that if Germany specifically draws the ire of Russia, gas supplies could be cut off, at great damage to the German economy and popular support for the current government. As I said, it suffers from the same weakness as the explanation above.

#### Anything to do with World War II or pacifism

From the Reuters article I already cited above:

> Unlike other Western allies, Germany did not supply weapons to Ukraine before Russia's invasion on Feb. 24 and even blocked other nations from sending German-origin military equipment, given a long-standing policy of not exporting arms to war zones. That policy had broad public support given Germany's bloody 20th-century history and resulting pacifism, and specifically guilt towards the Soviet Union over World War Two.

Again the question can be asked why sending other weapons can be considered pacifist and not exacerbating guilt over World War II, but not tanks.

**So what is the actual explanation?**

Comment: Depletions of Germany's own arsenal is only of concern with regards to releasing Bundeswehr gear.  Germany is also holding up transfer of other countries' L2s.

Comment: Apparently, we're not the only ones puzzled by the situation: FDP politician Marie-Agnes Strack-Zimmermann [has demanded](https://www.zeit.de/politik/deutschland/2023-01/marie-agnes-strack-zimmermann-leopard-panzer-ukraine-ampel-streit-rolf-muetzenich) that Scholz explain his reasoning here.

Comment: @nothingmaster It's all just part of growing pressure by the sending arms fraction. They could have demanded to send tanks 6 months ago where the front line was not that different, but somehow now seems the right moment for it, or not? Nobody outside of governments knows exactly.

Comment: German minister of foreign affairs Annalena Baerbock [clarified](https://www.zeit.de/politik/ausland/ukraine-krieg-russland-newsblog-live#event_id=ekz5bozg6rZWh9iJYRWq) today that Germany would not prevent other countries from giving Leopard 2s to Ukraine after all.

Answer (score 7):

Quite a lot of people are speculating, and I doubt that the truth will be really clear even when people write their memoirs and the files are declassified. But there are three or four things to look at:

- **Coordinated with allies, or together with allies?**
  I'm aware of just *one* example of modern western MBTs going to Ukraine. That's 14 British Challengers. Plenty of countries have delivered refurbished ex-Soviet tanks. The Americans have delivered wheeled HIMARS and promised Bradley IFVs. The Germans have delivered tracked MLRS, self-propelled howitzers, and promised Marder IFVs. The French have delivered wheeled howitzers and promised wheeled recon tanks (with a 105mm cannon, but not a MBT).
  So Germany is not exactly trailing the crowd when it comes to modern, tracked AFV. Neither is it leading, and considering the size and location of Germany one might argue that it should be leading. The German government has said **publicly** that it wants to coordinate, and reportedly said **privately** that it wants the US to promise Abrams first. ([Süddeutsche Zeitung](https://www.sueddeutsche.de/politik/ukraine-leopard-panzer-bundesregierung-1.5734901), a reasonably reputable newspaper in Germany.) Personally I don't buy some of the explanations why the Abrams is less suitable than the Leo.
  A cynical view of the Cold War could be that Europe 'got volunteered' to become the battlefield between the US and the Soviet Union if it had ever turned hot. So now Germany wants the US to make the first move in the new escalation, rather than leaving countries closer to Russia to do it.
- **German Army Leopards, German industry Leopards, or other Leopards?**
  There are (presumably *mostly* operational) Leopard 2 in German Army use, other (second-hand, partly refurbished, presumably not *quite* operational) Leopard 2 and Leopard 1 in the stocks of the German defense industry, and Leopards owned by other states. Germany could decide/allow to release tanks from any or all categories. (The big plus of sending Leopards, and not Challengers or Leclerc, is that many countries could pitch in to create a battalion or two. Compare the deliveries of MLRS or PzH2000 from various nations.)
  Some observers make the very good case that the German Army has no tanks to spare. So why not release the others? Germany *might* think that if it allows the transfer of, say, Polish Leopards, and the German industry stocks are not yet refurbished, there would be political pressure to divert German *Army* stocks.
- **What then?**
  Ukraine is not just asking for Leopard tanks, they would also like ATACMS or something like it, fighter jets, warships, etc. The moment Germany says 'yes' to Leopards, it will be badgered to provide something else.
- **Dynamics in the Social-Democrat Party**
  The SPD has a left wing which is critical of NATO, critical of the Bundeswehr, and rather proud of Willy Brandt's [Ostpolitik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostpolitik). It also has a right wing supportive of NATO and the Bundeswehr in general, and the Ukraine in this case. Some party members are likely to bolt whichever way Chancellor Scholz decides, so he decides as slowly as possible.
  *Follow-up: This morning (22-Jan-2023) there are [news](https://www.tagesschau.de/inland/innenpolitik/spd-aussenpolitik-101.html) about a position paper which may either clarify the strategic outlook, or produce yet another compromise.*

---

I don't buy the energy angle any more. So far the winter was exceptionally warm, storage is rather full, and it would take much more than *not* delivering Leopards to make Russia reopen the pipelines.

The WWII 'guilt trip' angle seems more relevant, as part of my 4th bullet point. The public debate in Germany centers on sending 'defensive' weapons, while tanks are the stereotypical 'offensive' weapon. That has nothing to do with military realities, only with perceptions of the general population.

Comment: "considering the size and location of Germany one might argue that it should be leading" France is also similarly located and sized. If anything they both should lead together. And the nature of EU is basically that there is no leader and all decisions are taken together (more or less) even if that takes longer (which in a war is deadly). But traditionally in the EU there isn't really a leading nation.

Comment: @Trilarion, that is a point, but Germany is both bigger than France, and closer to Russia. It has also fought Russia/the Soviet Union twice this century, so letting France take diplomatic center stage might be a very good thing ...

Comment: "So why not release the others?" Because they would also need to be replaced? If Germany has no tanks to spare then maybe other nations (Spain, Italy, ..) have not either.

Comment: "has also fought Russia/the Soviet Union twice this century" Not this century ;) but I get what you mean. I think this war has nothing to do with past world wars but other people might disagree.

Comment: @Trilarion, that's why there is a very good case to build a composite battalion or two of various countries' Leos. Everybody gives a few, and the spare parts and training is compatible.

Comment: @Trilarion, I'm getting old, it seems. And this war has *everything* to do with the last century. With the end of WWI, the dynamics after the breakup of Austria-Hungary, with the famine, with Russian paranoia and Russia's wish for buffer states, with Russia's nostalgia for Empire.

Comment: Okay there are historic roots but I somehow don't understand that there is a special responsibility to help Ukraine now on the basis that you have fought Russia before twice already. I'm sympathetic towards Ukraine but I don't think support for Ukraine should depend on past involvement in wars. That sounds too much like holding grudges.

Comment: @Trilarion, German soldiers murdered a lot of Ukrainians in WWII. Germany really *does* feel sorry about it, and I'm quite certain they would send more weapons if Ukraine wasn't fighting *another* victim of German aggesssion.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. Germans are mostly afraid of Russian nuclear weapons and used to be dependent on cheap Russian oil/gas. But for example Britain has never killed many Ukrainians or Russians (in the last last century, maybe more in the century before that). Still they seem to deliver a comparable amount of arms to Ukraine. Why if not because they believe Ukraine's cause is more just?

Comment: @Trilarion, I think all Western governments (and the majorities of their citizens) agree that Russia is the aggressor. And they have all taken steps which are unprecedented in living memory. I'd say that Germans are concerned about Russian nukes, but also getting inured to the repetition of the threats, and 'cold turkey' on the gas. Things might look different if this winter had been exceptionally cold, but it was the opposite.

Comment: *German Army Leopards, German industry Leopards, or other Leopards?*  Well, that's easy enough to answer if it's about blocking the release of Polish L2s.

Comment: @Trilarion & Italian Philosophers Slovakian defense minister says the news it would donate Leopards is fake news. Czech defense ministry "Nobody asked or invited us to send Leopards". Portugal only wants to send logistics. Netherlands only money. Canada and Spain said they wouldn't join. It basically leaves Poland and Finland, of which so far neither actually officially asked Germany to allow export.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica, Ukraine is also publicly asking for **German** Leopards, without being quite clear if they would be satisfied with refurbished ones from industry stocks late in 2023 or sometime 2024. (What they *need* is a couple hundred, right now ...) So giving Poland a re-export license would certainly play into that debate.

Comment: @Trilarion: "Why if not because they believe Ukraine's cause is more just?" I suspect that quite a few more in Germany than in the UK think negotiations will be how this war ends. OTOH, even in the the US, Gen. Milley is somewhat known for being a skeptic that the war will end this year. There's also the less talked about issue that some Leopards were destroyed in Syria, mostly because Turkish forces used them poorly. So, there's that prospect that a small-ish number of Western tanks provided to Ukraine will do little more than possibly provide Russia with some PR wins.

Comment: ... and possibly with a "tech preview" that would allow the Russians to calibrate their tactics and response before Ukraine can field them in significant numbers. We've already seen some of that with Russia's use of Lancet drones (mostly to take out arty and AA), which doesn't get all that much press in the West, but it's pretty real nonetheless--look at some weapon tracker blogs.

Comment: Here are some articles about the Turkish Leopard losses https://www.bellingcat.com/news/mena/2017/02/12/battle-al-bab-verifying-turkish-military-vehicle-losses/ https://nationalinterest.org/blog/buzz/germany%E2%80%99s-leopard-2-tank-syria-was-beaten-badly-battle-why-78441

Comment: One thing that was interesting about the question why not also sending Abrams M1 was that they are supposed to be difficult to train on and maintain. I wonder is there a comparison between Leopard 2 and Abrams M1 which of those is easier to train on and maintain? If one of them won in this category that would also be a selling point for the respective producer.

Answer (score 2):

One of the earlier stated reasons on Jan 6, albeit from some a somewhat lower-ranked official [was](https://youtu.be/XbxJYDHUjno?t=776) that they apparently saw Leopard [2] tanks as having much more offensive potential; literally that official ("SPD defense policy spokesman Wolfgang Hellmich") said Marders were "tanks for defense" (Panzer zur Verteidigung) while Leopards were "tanks for attack" (Angriffspanzer). (One may of course dispute this dichotomy.)

[image]

As an aside, according the same source, [Euro]Spike missiles that apparently equip some [modernized] Marders ([A5](https://www.janes.com/defence-news/news-detail/german-army-marder-1-ifv-upgrade-moves-ahead)) apparently cannot be given to Ukraine, due to Israeli opposition to that delivery. OTOH, the older Milan ATGMs can be given.

Comment: Do drive Russia out of Crimea, tanks for attack are obviously required.

Comment: Problem with low-ranked officials is that they hardly have the authority to speak for the whole party or even government. This guy can rule out delivering these tanks but that doesn't mean some higher ranking official will agree to exactly this next week.

Comment: @Trilarion: agreed, and in hindsight they were overriden. This answer is/was more to illustrate what o.m. wrote rather abstract.ly about the "dynamics in the Social-Democrat Party".

Answer (score 2):

Today, Germany, the US and other European nations decided to send tanks (of type Leopard 2 or M1 Abrams) to Ukraine, so the conclusion would be that last week they simply didn't have consensus about that yet and now they have.

Based on how the decision to send tanks is [phrased in Germany](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2023/jan/25/us-m1-abrams-biden-tanks-ukraine-russia-war) "This decision follows our well-known line of supporting Ukraine to the best of our ability. We are acting in a closely coordinated manner internationally." my guess is that Germany was simply afraid of being pushed to act alone and being singled out by Russia and rather wanted to act within a broad but united alliance for sending tanks, which is now happening.

Answer (score 0):

Might be due to public opinion. They say [here](https://www.anews.com.tr/world/2023/01/19/most-germans-against-sending-leopard-tanks-to-ukraine) that in a recent survey there were more against it among German people than for it. Support of Scholz is quite low recently so I guess he should really follow the public opinion in the important issues.

Comment: The question does not primarily concern giving German Leopard 2 to Ukraine but allowing other countries to give their own Leopard 2 away. On this issue the German public is more in favor than against. From your source: "Despite the reticence of the YouGov poll respondents towards having their country export the tanks, most are not opposed to other countries doing so. A total of 47% would be in favour, with 38% against and 16% undecided."

Comment: Actually the biggest opposition party (CDU) would send the tanks any day if only they were in power. The support might be below the one in Poland maybe (after all one country farer away) but still at least in line with the rest of Europe I'd say.

Comment: @Trilarion I have not seen data on the public support among the voters of the parties. But I can imagine that voters of SPD are more against it than those of the CDU.

Comment: @xyldke As of today, this exactly coincides with statements of foreign minister A. Baerbock. They do not send, but they also do not block if anyone asks for it. She also added that so far no one has asked for a permission officially.

Comment: Useful, but besides that Turkish agency, this is also the poll that TASS chose to highlight. Another poll showed a more even 46/43 split, but it might not have asked if they are undecided https://www.dw.com/en/german-chancellor-olaf-scholz-defends-decision-to-send-battle-tanks-to-ukraine/a-64509633 This one also has split by by party.

Answer (score -1):

If to assume the PR narrative that this is really the war between NATO and Russia already, not delivering tanks looks like a strange decision. Tanks are build for the war, there is nothing else they are good for. Now it is the war so it should be time to get them moving.

But ... maybe Europe still does not think it is **they** war?

The countries care not to weaken they own defenses too much. When (if) Russia will come to the territory of EU, it must be enough Leopards to greet them.